# Can (should) I use PHP to alter HTML page before serving, based on class attribute values

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'd like an easy way for content contributors with limited coding experience to designate the expiration date for selected content on existing HTML (PHP) pages on our site. I'd prefer to remove the content server-side so it isn't still available in the source code.

Illustration of a potential solution I am mulling over:

```
<div class="story"> ... </div>
```

Let's say I'd like the above div and its contents to disappear starting on June 1, 2011. So I would add a value to the class attribute:

```
<div class="story disappears-20110601"> ... </div>
```

Then I would have to write some code (xpath?) to locate all elements that have a class value with a pattern like ="... disapears-`YYYYMMDD`". If the date reference is valid, and that date is today or earlier, the code would remove the entire div and its contents from the DOM, and then serve the page without the expired div.

Before I try to set this up, what do you think of the concept? Is it feasible? If implemented sitewide, would it be a horrible resource hog?

Comment: Do the stories come from a database or is it all fixed html pages?

Comment: My opinion is you may be going about it the wrong way.  Where is this content originating from?  RSS Feed?  Back-end Database?  You should be able to filter the construction of the html based on what is available, rather than destructing html based off of what should not be available.

Comment: if you do end up doing it through html dont use the class attr. use `data-disappears`. http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: Looks like you want to emulate a database using HTML. This is more the purpose of XML, not really HTML. Using real XML you could use your own nodes and attributes like `<story disappears="20110601">` Since you have PHP at hand, I wouldn't bother using XML and would switch to a CMS like approach and a database.

Comment: There is no database, no RSS. :( HTML content is hand coded, or should I say WYSIWIG'd, by a dispersed group of not-very-techie Dreamweaver users. I swear I'm pushing for Drupal. Uphill battle. I'll look at the data-disappears article, thanks.

Comment: Current status: I'm just telling people to wrap the content like this:

`<?php if (time() < strtotime('2011-06-01 22:00')) {  ?>
<div class="story"> ... </div>
<?php } ?>`

In case someone else is looking for a simple 'n' dirty way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A much better way is to store the content in a database table and assign the expiration date via a `DATETIME` field. Using a css class for this is a little square-peg.

Comment: No database available. (Not my fault, I swear.) I'm pushing hard to implement an open source CMS (problem solved) but the site is more or less hand coded until I prevail....

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do that using Regexp, but I assume it /could/ (doesn't meant it will) get a little bit messy. I suggest using a database if you have access to one, if not store the stories into separate files (in one directory) and then load/delete/edit them via file-name.

Doing that through HTML would be unpleasant, in my opinion.

EDIT:

```
<?php
    $html_content = file_get_contents('...');
    preg_match('/class="story disappears-(\d*)"/i', $html_content, $match_array)
    foreach($match_array as $val) {
        if (intval($val) < intval(date('Ymd'))) {
            $new_html_content = preg_replace('/(<div class="story disappears-'. $val .'">.*<\/div>)/', '',  $html_content);
            echo $new_html_content;
        }
    }
?>
```

Just a side note, you should try debugging this first, I might've done some mistake since I didn't use php in a while. However, if you stumble upon any errors, let me know in the comments, so I can update the code.

Comment: and likewebbiedave suggested: if you have access to a database, you should add a DATETIME field type.

Comment: No database available. About 3/4 of the content contributors are not sophisticated tech people, let's say, but can open Dreamweaver and type. Once we get to the level of including properly named files that aren't in the WYSIWIG, it just will be too hard for them. Better to send themselves an email reminder to delete the content.... But I think I can get their heads wrapped around the idea of going into code view and adding a class....

Comment: Oh, I usually find it simpler of building a CMS for my clients than expecting them to do anything. Trust me, you'll just get disappointed. :( But you could use something like... (edits answer)

Comment: LOL "...expecting them to do anything." This is for where I work, so the users are coworkers. I know they could do it!! Maybe.

Comment: Okay, so I updated the answer, try that code, it might spit out some error, I didn't debug it, like it says, but if something's off, I let me know in the comments so we can fix it (or maybe you're confident enough to fix it on your own)

Comment: Okay, so mine seems to be working fine, just add a semicolon at the end of the preg_match statement.

Comment: You rock! I got pulled off this for today but will play with it as soon as I can, probably tomorrow. Great thanks for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for you:

```
<?php

$content = <<<EOF
<div>
some text 1
<div class="story disappears-20110101"> 20110101 </div>
<div class="story disappears-20110601"> 20110601 </div>
some text 2
</div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$expired = $xpath->query('//*[contains(@class, \'disappears-\')]');
$remove = array();
foreach ($expired as $n)
    if (preg_match('~disappears-(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})~', $n->getAttribute('class'), $m))
        if (time() > mktime(0, 0, 0, $m[2], $m[3], $m[1]))
            $remove[] = $n;
foreach ($remove as $n)
    $n->parentNode->removeChild($n);

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: I like to use [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) for this kind of stuff as I'm used to jquery selectors : you could then do something like `foreach(pq("div[class^=disappears]") as $div) { do something }`

Comment: Oh, I like your approach better than mine! Actually, I'm not even sure if mine's functional... I'm more of a ruby person.

Answer (score 0):

I mean there has to be a database available. Even if the pages are hand-coded, you can have them upload each page to your server, and have the back-end create a database entry that correlates to the uploaded page. this database entry could store info about the uploaded page such as the expire date. This also makes it easier organize/serve the page.

Comment: Hahaha! But, no, it's put together in Dreamweaver with PHP includes for the parts the non-techies don't have to touch. Hey, we got the OK for PHP, so that's a plus.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath 1.0 will select the desired elements:

```
//*[
   20110601
 >= 
   substring-before(
      substring-after(
         concat(
            ' ',
            normalize-space(@class),
            ' '
         ),
         ' disappears-'
      ),
      ' '
   )
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I will put on my learning hat and play with it tomorrow. I'm very grateful.